# How to remove all elements from a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

Why doesn't this code remove all the elements from a vector? Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
  vec.erase(vec.begin());
```

Comment: Is this an academic question? Otherwise use `vec.clear()`. And change the title. Otherwise people might think you want to know how to remove all elements from a vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `i` and `vec.size()` cross paths at about half the original vector size. You can simply write `while (!vec.empty()) …`.

Note that clearing a vector by repeatedly removing the first element takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time (`vec.clear()` takes O(1) unless the elements have a non-trivial destructor, in which case it takes O(n)).

Unless you're doing this for fun, use `vec.clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that all memory is released immediately, there is an established idiom:

```
std::vector<YourTypeHere>().swap(vec);
```

This creates a temporary vector which is initially empty, swaps its contents with your vector, and then the temporary dies at the semicolon.